# Javascript RegExp Non-white character fail

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this work

#### Example 1

```
re = new RegExp('\\$\\[(.+)\\]\\(([S,M,L]),([L,C,R])\\)', 'g')
'$[sds](S,L)'.replace(re, function(a,b,c,d) { 
        console.log(a,b,c,d); return 'test'; 
})
```

and this doesn't

#### Example 2

```
re = new RegExp('\\$\\[(\S+)\\]\\(([S,M,L]),([L,C,R])\\)', 'g')
'$[sds](S,L)'.replace(re, function(a,b,c,d) { 
     console.log(a,b,c,d); return 'test'; 
})
```

The only difference between the two being that Example 1 has `.+`, while example 2 has `\S+`.

`\S+` should match the `sds` in between the brackets, just the same as `.+`

Comment: How does `([S,M,L]),([L,C,R])` as a part of a RegEx make any sense? Shouldn't it be `([SML]),([LCR])` or `(S|M|L),(L|C|R)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in the `\S`:

```
new RegExp('\\$\\[(\\S+)\\]\\(([S,M,L]),([L,C,R])\\)', 'g')
```

This is it working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtXLN/

As pointed out in a comment, your Regex is a bit off:

```
new RegExp('\\$\\[(\\S+)\\]\\(([SML]),([LCR])\\)', 'g')
```